# How to most elegantly replace Courier New with another font system-wide?

Tags: fonts, browser

I am annoyed by Courier New on different web sites (most notably, GitHub) and would like to replace it with another font (say, Liberation Mono). I would like the solution to work in all browsers (so not to be browser specific), and I wouldn't like to uninstall all MS core fonts (I like the others).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to do it following this article: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Fonts

Just created `~/.fonts.conf` with following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">

<fontconfig>
  <!-- Replace Courier with a better-looking font -->
  <match target="pattern" name="family">
    <test name="family" qual="any"><string>Courier New</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign">
      <string>Liberation Mono</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

and didn't even had to log out in order to make effective, just restarted Chromium.

Comment: I had to replace `mode="assign"` with `mode="assign"  binding="same"` when attempting do this with Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Your GNOME font settings are in System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Fonts. There you can set which default fonts you want to use for different things (Application font is the only one I've found to affect web sites). The changes are immediate, but don't work on GitHub (probably because they have specified a font rather than leaving it to the system).

To override web site fonts, I don't think there's any setting to override for all browsers - You'll have to configure per browser, for example Edit -> Preferences -> Content -> Fonts & Colors -> Advanced -> Allow ... for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

How about installing only required fonts from MS core fonts i.e downloading each fonts and configuring each browsers to your priority fonts ?