# Broken fonts for code formatting blocks in slack and chrome in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fonts, slack

After I changed some fonts in tweaks-tool, in some programs (Slack, Chrome) font formatting for blocks of code became broken.

I tried to restore defaults, but fonts in code blocks still ugly.
How it can be fixed?

Ubuntu 18.04

Example of ugly code formatting fonts in slack:
[image: Screenshot of ugly code formatting fonts render in slack]

And normally should look like this:
https://get.slack.help/hc/article_attachments/360003366488/inlinecode.png

Answer (score 2):

Heavily inspired by a [similar resolution to a different problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/28433/459992), this is the simplest way to fix horrible looking code fonts in slack without having to re-install chrome or other drastic measures.

1. Run the `/slackdevtools` command to open the Chrome devtools for slack (the slack interface is Chromium based)
2. Inspect any message with a codeblock and identify the culprit font by editing the css `font-family` and progressively removing fonts until it fixes itself. (In my case it was `Courier New` making it look crap)
3. Override the offending font with a font of your choice (or just `monospace`, Bitstream is just a personal favourite) by adding something like this to your `~/.fonts.conf`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">

<fontconfig>
  <!-- Replace Courier with a better-looking font -->
  <match target="pattern" name="family">
    <test name="family" qual="any"><string>Courier New</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign">
      <string>Bitstream Vera Sans Mono</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

4. Quit and re-open slack!

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 19.10 and ran into the same problem after making font changes using the Tweaks tool.

Do the following:

Make sure that the Fixed-Width font in [chrome://settings/fonts](http://chrome://settings/fonts) is set to MonoSpace.

Add the file ~/.fonts.conf with the following code:

```
<match target="font" >
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign"><bool>false</bool></edit>
</match>
```

Uninstall chrome and reinstall chrome

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it seems msfonts is the culprit.
[Firefox fonts changed after install ttf-mscorefonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412828/firefox-fonts-changed-after-install-ttf-mscorefonts)

Did you install something like Visual Studio Code before your last OS restart?

I tried removing mscorefonts here
[How to remove ttf-mscorefonts completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57735/how-to-remove-ttf-mscorefonts-completely)

and everything goes back to what it was.